# override "C-SPC" set-mark-command

Tags: key-bindings, debugging

I'm using [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) and experimenting with it trying to find the right key binding

As per **expand-region** README it binded to

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'er/expand-region)
```

But I'm not satisfied, I thing it better keybind would be

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-SPC") 'er/expand-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'er/contract-region)
```

Since we nomally use **C-SPC** to **set-mark**, which would be ovrrided by this config, but **C-SPC** when region selected will reset the region the reset to the current-cursor-position, so binding **er/contract-region** to **C-SPC** make sense so I did.

```
(defun my-contract-region()
    (interactive)
    (if (use-region-p)
        (er/contract-region)
        (set-mark-command)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'my-contract-region)
```

but when using in I couldn't figure out the argument error

[image]

Edited 1:

Yes I turned on debugging but, still could'nt figure out why, :(

[image]

Comment: The message gives a good hint.  Check that the functions get the right number of arguments.  Also consider to use `call-interactively' for the calls.

Comment: @MarcoWahl samel problem when using `call-interactively`

Comment: I recommend `M-u` as keybinding for `expand-region`.

Comment: @Stefan `M-u` is binded to `upcase-word` which i use regulary.

Comment: To make easier sense of the error message, load the source code (`.el`, not `.elc`) first. (And set variable `debug-on-error` to `t`.) And use `C-h f` to check the expected (i.e., mandatory minimal) number of args for each of the functions you are using.

Comment: @rho: duh, sorry, I meant `C-M-u` (which by default is bound to `backward-up-list` which is conceptually a similar operation to `expand-region` (in many cases you can pretty easily get one's behavior from the other).

Comment: @Drew I just tried as you said but couldn't figure it out myself, add the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Stefan that's rite but It more over the question why the the override function isn't working, I don't have trouble resetting the keybinds.

Comment: `C-h f set-mark-command` tells you that it has one required argument. You are invoking it without passing it any argument. See other suggestions to use `call-interactively` or just call it with the proper argument.

Comment: @Drew as per set-mark-command `With no prefix argument, set the mark at point, and push the old mark position on local mark ring.  Also push the new mark on global mark ring, if the previous mark was set in another buffer.`

Comment: It tells you this: `(set-mark-command ARG)`, which means that when invoked from Lisp it **must be passed** `ARG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding argument, **er/contract-region** is working perfectly, thanks @Drew @MarcoWahl I made the mistake using **call-interactively** Sorry, I don't really understand elisp. my final snippet looks like:

```
(defun my-contract-region()
      (interactive)
      (if (use-region-p)
          (er/contract-region 1)
          (call-interactively 'set-mark-command)))
```